# Document.QuerySelector to fill a unique value with prepend and append

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a JS code to fill up elements with their already filled up values as desribed in the table link image below:

[image]
For this code below, what modifcation will be required to get the desired final value?

```
var data = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']").forEach(x => x.value
if( data > 0){
  var result = '(' + data + ')'
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']").forEach(x => x.value = result)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you call `querySelectorAll` twice or what `data` is for:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']")
  .forEach(o => {
    if (o.value && !isNaN(o.value) && o.value < 0.9) o.value = `(${o.value})`;
  });
```

```html
<div><input id="1253~blah1" value="0.1" /></div>
<div><input id="1253~blah2" value="0.2" /></div>
<div><input id="1253~blah3" value="" /></div>
<div><input id="1253~blah4" value="0.9" /></div>
<div><input id="1253~blah5" value="11.2" /></div>
```

Comment: This answer is better if OP is referring to inputs when saying, "fill up elements", but mine is better if referring a generic element like `<p>` or a `<div>`

Comment: @PsiKai OP used `value` so I did too.

Comment: Perfectly valid assumption to make

Comment: @JohnnyMopp, Your code is working, but I need to add one more condition, if value =>0.9 then also it should NOT do the prepend and append function and leave the value as it is. Please see here = https://i.ibb.co/6RsBgsK/java.jpg

Comment: Please try changing `if (o.value) ....` to `if (o.value && (!(isNaN(o.value)) && !(o.value >= 0.9))) ...`. The added conditions check whether `o.value` is a number & whether it is "NOT" >= 0.9. Thus, the prefix & suffix paranthesis are "NOT" added if it is >= 0.9

Comment: @VickyLahkar Updated with new conditions.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thank you. This finally solved my querry.

Answer (score 0):

User `innerText` instead of `value` when setting the result in your elements.  `value` is an html property and doesn't necessarily mean what's viewed on the screen.

```
if( data > 0) {
  var result = '(' + data + ')'
  document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']").forEach(x => x.innerText = result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']")
  .forEach(o => {
    if (o.value && !isNaN(o.value) && o.value < 0.9) o.value = `(${o.value})`;
  });
```

This is the code which solved my query. Thank you everyone.