# Javascript to fill definite values only

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a JS code to fill up elements with their already filled up values as desribed in the table here

[image]

The JS code suggested by some members here which has worked partially is this:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']")
  .forEach(o => {
    if (o.value) o.value = `(${o.value})`;
  });
```

Problem is that I need this condition that, if value =>0.9 then also it should NOT do the prepend and append function and leave the value as it is like shown in the table picture above. The code above is filling for all non-blank values (including values=>0.9). Please help me to solve my problem. Regards, Vicky.

Comment: Change it to `if (+o.value < 0.9)` I thought you said my suggestion didn't work. It appears it did because you didn't mention this 0.9 value, in fact you didn't mention the nature of the value either. Also, `o.value` is a string not a real number -- it needs to be converted (hence the `+`)

Comment: @zer00ne, this code if (+o.value < 0.9) is not woking correctly. It is filling blank values also. I want ONLY values < 0.9 to be filled (prepended and appended). Other values are to be left as it is.  Thank you.

Comment: I can only answer with what I'm given, and on rare I'll occasions answer successfully if I grok a questioner's real problem. Your problem is fundamental and so to is my comment. If it doesn't work then it is a typo or there are important details missing in your question. I'm sorry, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: @zer00ne - to understand the context, I had to put the time & effort to review [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71359082/13658816). I felt that "that" answer (on the link) simply requires an additional condition (on the `if`). I 100% empathize with you.

Comment: Thank you jsN00b and zer00ne for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelectorAll("[id^='1253']")
  .forEach(o => {
    if (o.value && parseFloat(o.value) < 0.9)
      o.value = `(${o.value})`;
  });
```

just do add another condition `parseFloat(o.value) < 0.9` means only the value with below 0.9 will be changed. `parseFloat` parses the `o.value` to `float` so it can be compared to `0.9`

Comment: Please consider using `&&` in this line: `if (o.value and ` (instead of `and`).

Comment: Also, please check if `parseInt` may need to be replaced with `parseFloat` (in case the comparison involves decimals).

Comment: @jsN00b okay thank you so much. I almost forgot.